# How to prevent one of the state variables of a child page from changing its value?How to retain initial value as props from the parent page? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My child page opens when a flag in my parent called 'isChildOpen' is true. Now I want to make the state variable filtered2 in my child unchangable. filtered and filtered2 should get same value from the parent when I open the child page but while filtered can change during any operation in the child, filtered2 should retain its initial value of the opening of child every time. It should get its value from the parent when the parent is opened but not change due to any operations in the child.

Child Code

```
 class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
       data: this.props.data,
       filtered: this.props.filtered
       filtered2: this.props.filtered
       };
     }
```

I have tried Object.freeze but is of no help.

This is how the child opens from the parent page

```
         {this.state.isChildOpen &&
         <Child 
            data={this.state.data}
            filtered={this.state.filtered}
          />}
```

Can anyone help me in this regard? filtered can change during any operations in the child but filtered2 should retain the initial value after the child is just opened.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use `this.props.filtered.slice()`

This would make a replica of  the value

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.state.isChildOpen &&
   <Child 
     data={this.state.data}
     filtered={this.state.filtered}
     filtered2={this.state.filtered2}
   />}
```

when `this.state.isChildOpen` switch to false and then again to true a new instance of `Child`  is created and so the constructor is again invoked with a new value of `filtered2`.

you should pass `isChildOpen` as a prop down to `Child` and handle the rendering from there

```
<Child 
  data={this.state.data}
  filtered={this.state.filtered}
  filtered2={this.state.filtered2}
  isChildOpen={this.state.isChildOpen}
/>}


class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
         filtered2: this.props.filtered2
       };
     }

     render() {
       const { data, filtered, isChildOpen } = this.props; // this props will update following the parent
       const { filtered2 } = this.state; //this prop will be controlled by the child and will keep the value once the instantiation
       if(!isChildOpen) {
          return null;
       }
       // otherwise render the component
     }
```

Comment: I dont understand how you are retaining the filtered2 variable. filtered2 should get its initital value from parent but its value should not change due to any operation in the child

Comment: you set just filtered2 as part of the state of the Child whether the other props are reflecting the value of the parents